# How to get the id for document in collection?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how to get id for document a ?

```
const name=prod['categ'].value;

const a=db.collection('Categories').whereEqualTo("Name", name);

b=a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not yet executing the query, which is necessary to get its ID.

Something like:

```
const query = db.collection('Categories').whereEqualTo("Name", name);

query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The majority of that code is copied straight from the Firebase documentation on [getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), so I recommend spending some time studying that.